# Which module is used for the effect ...?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

At http://acquiaprosper.fusiondrupalthemes.com/, their is a sliding product show case at the top banner:

[image]

Which modules are required? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This video podcast from mustardseed details how to set-up a view like that using Views Slideshow module.

http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode42

drupal.org/project/views_slideshow

Comment: I cant add that other link, stackoverflow spam protection kicked in I need more than 10 reps apparently!

Answer (score 1):

i think its their own code by using [jquery cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) . Try [UI carousel](http://drupal.org/project/uicarousel) , [views carousel](http://drupal.org/project/viewscarousel), [jcarousel](http://drupal.org/project/jcarousel)

Answer (score 1):

I would use views_slideshow as atomicjeep suggested. it's a great module that I have used several times.